# Using Spreadsheet Sort with Relative References and Multiple Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

**Here is the background**: I have multiple sheets with multiple columns of different data in each sheet.

**What I'd like to do**: I have used one sheet as a "base" sheet, linking "other sheets" to its data to retrieve it using relative references. Okay, fine, it works.

**The Issue**: When I sort the data on the base sheet, it also sorts it automatically on the other sheets. Great, that's expected. However, all the other various columns on the other sheets stay static, but the columns that are linked with the base sheet are the only ones that shift. This is a problem, because the data is now mismatching across rows.

**Question**: How can I make the columns on the other sheet "persistent" even if I sort the data on the base sheet?

Comment: Can you share a sample or copy of your spreadsheet? Remove sensitive data if any.

Answer (score 0):

the only way is to bind your "static column" via a common link (be it ID or row position or something else that fits your needs)

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do this?